# Python webscraping tables with multiple header rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working through an issue with scraping a webtable using python.  I have been scraping what I would call 'standard' tables for a while and I feel like I understand that reasonably well.  I define a standard table as having a structure like:

```
<table>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Bill</th>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Ben</th>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Barry</th>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have now come across a table instance which has a slightly different structure and I can't figure out how to get the data out of it in the format I need.  The format I am now trying to scrape is:

```
<table>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Bill</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Ben</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Barry</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
Bill,1,2,3,4
Ben,2,3,4,1
Barry,3,4,1,2
```

I assume the problem I am encountering is that because the header is stored in a separate tr row, I only get an output of:

```
Bill
Ben
Barry
```

I am wondering if the solution is to traverse the rows and determine if the next tag is a th or td and then perform an appropriate action?  I'd appreciate any advice on how the code I am using to test this could be modified to achieve the desired output.  The code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t_obj = """<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Bill</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Ben</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Barry</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(t_obj)

trs = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"row-class"})

for tr in trs:
    for th in tr.findAll('th'):
        print (th.get_text())
        for td in tr.findAll('td'):
            print(td.get_text())
            print(td.get_text())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I use 3 methods how to pair the two `<tr>` tags together:

- 1st method is using `zip()` and CSS selector
- 2nd method is using BeautifulSoup's method `find_next_sibling()`
- 3rd method is using `zip()` and simple slicing with custom step

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t_obj = """<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Bill</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Ben</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Barry</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(t_obj, 'html.parser')

for tr1, tr2 in zip(soup.select('tr.row-class'), soup.select('tr.row-class ~ tr:not(.row-class)')):
    print( ','.join(tag.get_text() for tag in tr1.select('th') + tr2.select('td')) )

print()

for tr in soup.select('tr.row-class'):
    print( ','.join(tag.get_text() for tag in tr.select('th') + tr.find_next_sibling('tr').select('td')) )

print()

trs = soup.select('tr')
for tr1, tr2 in zip(trs[::2], trs[1::2]):
    print( ','.join(tag.get_text() for tag in tr1.select('th') + tr2.select('td')) )
```

Prints:

```
Bill,1,2,3,4
Ben,2,3,4,1
Barry,3,4,1,2

Bill,1,2,3,4
Ben,2,3,4,1
Barry,3,4,1,2

Bill,1,2,3,4
Ben,2,3,4,1
Barry,3,4,1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('tr')
result = [[d[i].text]+[c.text for c in d[i+1].find_all('td')] for i in range(0, len(d), 2)]
```

To print your result:

```
print('\n'.join(f'{a[1:]},{",".join(b)}' for a, *b in result))
```

Output:

```
Bill,1,2,3,4
Ben,2,3,4,1
Barry,3,4,1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Process HTML to fit

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
t_obj = """<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Bill</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Ben</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <th>Barry</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc()
doc.loadHtml(doc.replaceReg(t_obj,"</tr>\s*<tr>",''))# merge tr
trs = doc.trs # get all tr
for tr in trs:
  tds = tr.children # get td and th
  data = [td.text for td in tds]
  print (data)
```

result:

```
['Bill', '1', '2', '3', '4']
['Ben', '2', '3', '4', '1']
['Barry', '3', '4', '1', '2']
```